# PowerShell 5.1 Can receiving function signature contain splatting parameter?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

Can you define a splatting parameter in a receiving function's signature?

```
function main {
   $test = @{p1='a';p2='b'}

   DoWork @test
}

function DoWork {
    param([?] @test) # line in question

    # Maybe call another function with it
    DoWork2 @test
}

main
```

Comment: `param([?] @test)` is not valid, parameter `p1` and `p2` must be defined in the `param` block of `DoWork` for it to bind them both properly.

Comment: You can have a  hashtable parameter or you can splat a hashtable (i.e. pass the values to the parameters defined by the keys).  I'm not sure which you're trying to do  (or both)

Comment: From what you've done in main, DoWork would need to have parameters named p1 and p2. like @SantiagoSquarzon said.

Comment: to be fair, if the function is not advanced, you can get away with having only one of the parameters defined or even none without getting any errors. if the functions is advanced you would get `ParameterBindingException`

Comment: @MikeShepard I updated OP: maybe I might need to call another function with same parameters (which might use some or all of the values). It is a global worthy parameter, but was trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Rod - if you're wanting to propagate the parameters to other functions, Santiago's answer about splatting PSBoundParameters is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you're looking for is to pass the same arguments used for `DoWork` to `DoWork2`, if that is the case, you can use the [automatic variable `$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psboundparameters) for this.

```bash
function DoWork {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4)

    DoWork2 @PSBoundParameters
}

function DoWork2 {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4)

    "'{0}' was called with the following parameters:" -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
    $PSBoundParameters.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        'Parameter: {0} // Argument: {1}' -f $_, $PSBoundParameters[$_]
    }
}
```

Below there is a minimal example of how this works:

```bash
PS /> DoWork a b c d

'DoWork2' was called with the following parameters:
Parameter: p1 // Argument: a
Parameter: p2 // Argument: b
Parameter: p3 // Argument: c
Parameter: p4 // Argument: d

PS /> DoWork -p4 hello -p2 world

'DoWork2' was called with the following parameters:
Parameter: p4 // Argument: hello
Parameter: p2 // Argument: world
```

It's important to understand that for this to work properly, both functions **must share the same parameter names** or an [Alias Attribute Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/alias-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) that matches the same parameter from the caller, i.e.:

```bash
param($p1, $p2, $p3, [alias('p4')] $somethingelse)
```

It's also worth noting that [`[cmdletbinding()]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2) and / or [`[parameter()]` attribute declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/parameter-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) will make your function act as an [Advanced Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2). **If you attempt to bind to a non existent parameter of an advanced function you would get a [ParameterBindingException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterbindingexception?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) as a result**.