# Pass [switch] inside Start-Job

Tags: powershell

There is a script for users to log in, it calls other scripts in turn, depending on the conditions.
In order to call scripts separately manually, the [switch]$Silent parameter has been added. Question - how to pass this parameter inside Start-Job? I tried to add to the list of arguments in different ways - the value always falls into the neighboring parameter, regardless of the order.
Main script example

```
Param(
    [string]$location = 'C:\Users',
    [switch]$Silent
)
    Start-Job -FilePath ".\Fonts_Install.ps1" -ArgumentList ($Silent,$location) | Wait-Job
```

Fonts_Install.ps1

```
    Param(
        [switch]$Silent = $false,
        [string]$location = '.'
    )
  $path_fonts = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts"
$Registry = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"

function WriteLog {
    Param ([string]$LogString)
    $Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    $LogMessage = "$Stamp $LogString"
    Add-content $LogFile -value $LogMessage
}
$Logfile = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Temp\fonts_install.log"

WriteLog "Silent $Silent"
WriteLog "location $location"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore

$SourceFolder = "$location\Fonts_Install"
$WindowsFonts = [System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection]::new()
$Fonts = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Include *.ttf, *.otf -Recurse -File
ForEach ($Font in $Fonts) {
    $Font_Name = $Font.Name
    $font_fullname = $Font.fullname
    if (Test-Path -PathType Leaf -Path "$path_fonts\$Font_Name") {
        WriteLog "Previously installed $Font_Name"
    }
    else {
        Copy-Item $Font -Destination "$path_fonts" -Force -Confirm:$false -PassThru
        $WindowsFonts.AddFontFile("$font_fullname")
        $ValueFont = "$path_fonts" + "\" + "$Font_Name"
        $Typeface = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface -ArgumentList "$font_fullname"
        [string]$FamilyFaceNames = $Typeface.FamilyNames.Values + $Typeface.FaceNames.Values
        $RegistryValue = @{
            Path  = $Registry
            Name  = $FamilyFaceNames
            Value = $ValueFont
        }
        if (Test-Path $Registry\$FamilyFaceNames) {
            Remove-ItemProperty -name $FamilyFaceNames -path $Registry
        }
        New-ItemProperty @RegistryValue
        WriteLog "New fonts installed $Font_Name"
    }
}  
    switch ($Silent) {
        $false {
            if ($Error.Count -gt 0) {
                for ($i = 0; $i -le ($Error.Items.Count + 1); $i++) {
                    $errMSG = "$Error"
                }
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$errMSG", "Error", "OK", "Error")
            }
            else {
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("ок", "Fonts", "OK", "Asterisk") | out-null
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. How did you conclude that "the value always falls into the neighboring parameter, regardless of the order"? What's the exact behavior you're observing?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Added the full text of the script, maybe it will help. When calling a script from another script using start-job, regardless of the order of $Silent and $location, the script does not work due to an incorrect path, it gets into the log

2022.07.13 17:08:13 Silent False
2022.07.13 17:08:14 location False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **specifying pass-through arguments via [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)'s `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) is limited to *positional* arguments**, which **prevents binding `[switch]` parameters**, whose arguments must by definition be *named*.

As a workaround, instead of using `-FilePath`, invoke your script via the `-ScriptBlock` parameter. Inside of a *script block* (`{ ... }`, named arguments may be used in script calls, as usual:

```bash
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

  # Set the current location to the same location as the caller.
  # Note: Only needed in *Windows PowerShell*.
  Set-Location -LiteralPath ($using:PWD).ProviderPath

  .\Fonts_Install.ps1 -Silent:$using:Silent $using:Location

} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

- Note the use of the `$using:` scope in order to embed variable values from the caller's scope in the script block that will execute in the background.
- You still need to refer to the `-Silent` parameter *by name*, and the whether the switch is on or off can be communicated by appending `:$true` or `:$false` to it, which is what `:$using:Silent` does.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, background jobs execute in a *fixed* location (working directory), namely the user's `Documents` folder, hence the `Set-Location` call to explicitly use the same location as the caller, so that the script file can be referenced by a relative path (`.\`). This is no longer necessary in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which now thankfully uses the same location as the calller.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works! I found and tried similar solutions, but there was no $using: and it doesn't work without it.
But I was not able to force the script to run from the same folder via .\Fonts_Install.ps1 - it worked only when the full path was specified, otherwise it swears "The name ".\Fonts_Install.ps1" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or executable program" . But these are trifles

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped, @StepanTerehov, Good point about the working directory, The problem is that in _Windows PowerShell_ background jobs execute in a _fixed_ working directory rather than in the caller's. Fortunately, this has been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+ - please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different alternative to [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72967196/15339544), this answer does not use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2) and uses a [`PowerShell` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) instead, using this method we can leverage the [automatic variable `$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psboundparameters).

Do note, that for this to work properly, both `.ps1` scripts must share the same parameter names or [Alias Attribute Declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/alias-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) that matches the same parameter from the caller. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72637885/15339544) for more details.

You can use these snippets below as a example for you to test how it works.

- **caller.ps1**

```bash
param(
    [string] $Path = 'C:\Users',
    [switch] $Silent
)

try {
    if(-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Path')) {
        $PSBoundParameters['Path'] = $Path
    }

    $ps = [powershell]::Create().
        AddCommand('path\to\myScript.ps1').
        AddParameters($PSBoundParameters)

    $iasync = $ps.BeginInvoke()
    # Do something else here while the .ps1 runs
    # ...
    # Get async result from the PS Instance
    $ps.EndInvoke($iasync)
}
finally {
    if($ps -is [IDisposable]) {
        $ps.Dispose()
    }
}
```

- **myScript.ps1**

```bash
# Note, since we're bounding this parameters from the caller.ps1,
# We don't want to assign Default Values here!
param(
    [string] $Path,
    [switch] $Silent
)

foreach($param in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Parameter = $param
        Value     = Get-Variable $param -ValueOnly
    }
}
```

A few examples:

```bash
PS /> .\caller.ps1

Parameter Value
--------- -----
Path      C:\Users
Silent    False

PS /> .\caller.ps1 -Path hello

Parameter Value
--------- -----
Path      hello
Silent    False

PS /> .\caller.ps1 -Path world -Silent 

Parameter Value
--------- -----
Path      world
Silent    True
```